# How to check if a raw disk added on a virtual machine is online independent of windows locale

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, locale, vmware

I have a scenario where I add a raw disk to a virtual machine from vmware. Then I run a scrip to format the raw disk and mount it. The script looks something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
target=$1
mount=$2
format=$3
script=/tmp/diskpart.$$
echo "list disk" >> $script
disks=$($diskpart /s $wscript | tee ${logfile} | awk '$1 == "Disk" && ($3 == "Online" || $3 == "Offline") {print $2}')
```

This works fine when the windows platform is in english, but when the windows platform is not english say french, this fails as 'Disk' is spelled as 'Disque'. Is there a locale independent way to determine if the disk is online and format it? I did search a lot but couldnt find a way

Answer (score 1):

This is Unix bash script. 
I'm 100% sure. It starts with shebang and contain PS incompatible syntax.

Sorry.